# How to send messages from activity to service and execute them while the service is running?

Tags: android, service, android-activity, handler, intentservice

I have an activity which starts an `IntentService`:

```
intent = new Intent(MyApplication.getAppContext(), MyService.class);
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS", value);
MyApplication.getAppContext().startService(intent);
```

The service starts a Bluetooth connection with the MAC address I sent.

```
device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(macAddress);

public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
    this.mmDevice = device;
    BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
    try {
        tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString(SPP_UUID));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mmSocket = tmp;
}
```

I listen:

```
while (true) {
    try {
        if (mmInStream.available() != 0) {
            bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);    
            String readMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
            sendMessageToActivity("incoming", readMessage);
        } else {
            SystemClock.sleep(100);
        }
```

And send received messages back to the activity:

```
public void sendMessageToActivity(String type, String message) {
    intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);
    intent.putExtra(type, message);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

I use a `BroadcastReceiver` to receive messages from the service:

```
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        updateUI(intent);
    }
};
```

I call from the activity (***part*** of the problem):

```
private void writeOut(final String message) {
    msg = message;
    byte[] send = msg.getBytes();
    MyService.write(send);
}
```

This is the service's static `write()` method:

```
public static void write(byte[] out) {
    // Create temporary object
    ConnectedThread r;
    // Synchronize a copy of the ConnectedThread
    synchronized (obj) {
        if (mState != STATE_CONNECTED)
            return;
        r = mConnectedThread;
    }
    // Perform the write unsynchronized
    r.write(out);`
}
```

**My problem:** All of the above works as intended except `MyService.write(send)`. UI gets stuck. I tried to use an `AsyncTask` but it didn't work. I think I need to stop using that static `write()` method and send messages to the service and let him do the job. I believe I need to initialize a `Handler` in the activity, send it to the service by the intent via `startService()`.

I want to keep track of the messages in and out from the service. It is working fine with incoming messages. I need to figure out a way to properly receive messages from the activity, execute them and then send information back to the activity.

Comment: is my question complicated?

Comment: you need to A/ not ask a second question just because your first question was not answered after 20 hours. B/ read about http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html C/define "didn't work" in the context of AsyncTask with details as to how you tried. D/ consider broadcast and receivers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, about [`IntentService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html):

> All requests are handled on a single worker thread -- they may take as long as necessary (and will not block the application's main loop), but only ***one*** request will be processed at a time.

So, consider moving your code to a [`Service`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html). I'm not sure about Bluetooth connections and [`NetworkOnMainThreadException`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html), but just in case: note that a `Service` runs on main UI thread, so to avoid of such exception, you will need something like `Thread` inside your service. Don't use [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), because *AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the most.)* Also note that the system will manage the service's lifecycle automatically, you *shouldn't*/ *cannot* interact with it in any static methods.

Now come back to your problem. The way you use broadcast receiver (to send messages from the service to the activity) is correct, but consider using [`ResultReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ResultReceiver.html) (available in API 3+). Using `ResultReceiver` is better than sending a wide broadcast message, I think. You can put a `ResultReceiver` into an `Intent`.

And to send messages from the activity to the service, I assume you moved to `Service`. You can put anything into an `Intent` and call `startService()` again to send it. You'll get the intent in [`onStartCommand()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand%28android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int%29). Or if you have bound the service using [this technique](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#CreatingBoundService), you could call the service's methods *directly* from inside the activity.

There are some sample projects working with services in the SDK — folder `[Android SDK]/samples/`. On emulators, you can test those projects in the app named API Demos.

Comment: Thank you for the information, gonna make the necessary changes and write back.

Comment: passing intents via startService() worked. My current setup is: IntentService with Threads for Bluetooth connection. Service-to-Activity: intent+Broadcast receiver. Activity-to-Service: intent-startService().

Comment: @wervdon You shouldn't use `IntentService`, I think. As the documentation says, every call to `startService()` will push new instance of the service into a queue. Every item in the queue will be popped out and executed. About `Service`, you can call `startService()` as many times as you want, but there will be only one instance of the service which runs in the background. I think you could consider moving to `Service`?

Comment: Read about it, you are right. Moved back to Service. Thanks for your concern.